# Can you modify variable in scope of decorated function

Tags: python, decorator

Take the below decorator example:

```
import functools

def my_decorator( func ):
   my_var = 1

   @functools.wraps( func )
   def wrapper( *args, **kwargs ):
      print my_var
      return func( *args, **kwargs )

   return wrapper

@my_decorator
def my_func( s ):
   print s
```

Is there a way to access and modify `my_var` in global scope?

Looking inside of the wrapped function using `globals()[ 'my_func' ]` I don't see any references to `my_var`, and yet I know that it has to be accessible by `my_func` as it calls `print my_var`.

Additionally I still need there to be a single instance of `my_var` per decorated function.

Comment: No, not easily.  And any attempt to is fragile and hard to read.

Comment: You mean `nonlocal my_var`? Is this Python 2 or 3?

Comment: @Ryan I should have specified, this is Python 2.7.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Do you want to access `my_var` from outside the decorator? Do you want `wrapper` or `my_decorator` to modify variables in the call site's scope? Do you want something else?

Comment: Perhaps you could explain more about what you hope to do.  There might be another way of solving the problem.

Comment: (If you mean from `my_func` rather than `wrapper`, the approach is the same – pass the dict/list/other mutable value in as an argument from `wrapper` to `my_func`.)

Comment: My use is for a memoization decorator that stores the function return cache as a variable defined in the decorator function. I want to be able to reset the cache.

Comment: @Ryan The modification of `my_var` needs to occur in global scope, not in `my_func` or `wrapper`. I'm fine with a solution that delves into the function private objects to accomplish this. I do not believe this is a duplicate of nonlocal not being in Python 2.x, as the problem isn't not being able to access it in `my_func`.

Comment: @JDN: Like I said, the solution’s the same: you can’t modify a variable, so you have to use a list/dict/other mutable wrapper.

Comment: Don't use a closure variable; make it a function attribute or something.

Comment: @user2357112: I see. Adding `my_var` as an attribute to the wrapped function would allow it to be modified in global scope while also preserving the ability to have one instance of `my_var` per wrapped function.

Comment: @Ryan: I don't think this is a duplicate of nonlocal not in Python 2.x as I specifically need it to be a per-wrapped function attribute. I'll edit the question to reflect this requirement.

Comment: @JDN yeah, if you simply wanted to *mutate* the variable, i.e. `my_memo_dict.clear()`, then you could hack something with `my_func.func_closure` and `my_func.func_code.co_freevars` but since functions are just objects, just add an attribute to it, it's a much cleaner solution. Anyway, hacking the `func_closure` won't allow you to *reassign*, but you could access and modify.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: I think this is the original solution I was looking for. As 
 you said it doesn't work with reassignment as in the stated question, but in my real usage it's a dictionary so mutation works. I will go with the function attribute way in my code as it's cleaner, but also will try hacking together something using `func_closure` for my own edification.

Comment: @JDN something like `i = my_func.func_code.co_freevars.index('my_var')` and `my_object = my_func.func_closure[i].cell_contents`. Note, I'm not sure if the `i` is guaranteed to line up for `func_code.co_freevars` and `func_closure`, it seems to, but as I said, hackey

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Yes, that appears to work and do what I originally wanted. I think it would be a good official answer for this question, with the addition of a disclaimer stating it is better to add `my_var` as an attribute to the passed in `func` in `my_decorator`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, @user2357112: It doesn't seem like adding `my_var` attribute to `func` in `my_decorator` solves the issue. I still need to access the original function, which requires me to use `my_func.func_closure` to access it in Python 2.x. In Python 3 this could be done using `__wrapped__`. Any thoughts? I can't seem to escape using `func_closure`.

Comment: I discovered that if you set the attribute before `@functools.wraps( func )` is called then it works as the attribute is copied over to the wrapper function. If attribute is first set inside of the wrapper it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @juanpa.arrivillaga showed in the comments, this is possible through free variable lookups and binding to function closure objects, as shown here:

```
i = my_func.func_code.co_freevars.index('my_var')
my_var = my_func.func_closure[i].cell_contents
```

The posted question is using an immutable object, so `my_var` could not be modified nor the underlying variable reassigned. This would only work if `my_var` was mutable.

A better solution would be to include this variable as an attribute in the wrapped function, which through the `@functools.wraps` decorator will be copied over to the wrapper function along with all other attributes. However, it still requires `my_var` to be a mutable object for modification to work.

Example of above shown here:

```
import functools

def my_decorator( func ):
   my_var = func.my_var = {}

   @functools.wraps( func )
   def wrapper( *args, **kwargs ):
      print my_var
      return func( *args, **kwargs )

   return wrapper

@my_decorator
def my_func( s ):
   print s

my_func( "First call" )
my_func.my_var[ 'Testing' ] = '123'
my_func( "Second call" )
```

Output:

```
{}
First call
{'Testing': '123'}
Second call
```